# sfConfig::get in a task in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have tried to use a parameter in my app.yml file inside a task in symfony 1.4, but it doesnt get the value.

```
sfConfig::get()
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default tasks are ran only with a project - meaning they don't have access to your settings in app.yml. You either need to:

- explicitly pass an app parameter every time you call the task, this is done like:

  ```
  php symfony ns:task --application=frontend
  ```
- add it as a default parameter in your `configure()`:

  ```
  $this->addOptions(array(
    new sfCommandOption('application', "app", sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', "frontend")
  ));
  ```

Comment: The signature of the sfCommandOption constructor is `($name, $shortcut = null, $mode = null, $help = '', $default = null)` - You put "frontend" as the shortcut name of the command option, where it should've gone at the end as the 5th param to be the default value.